# Terraform ARN ID of Subnet in IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, terraform

I'm trying to create a custom IAM role with Terraform:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "prod_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:GetConsole*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:${var.aws_region}:*:subnet/${aws_subnet.prod1.id}",
                "arn:aws:ec2:${var.aws_region}:*:subnet/${aws_subnet.prod2.id}",
                "arn:aws:ec2:${var.aws_region}:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:${var.aws_region}:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:${var.aws_region}:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:${var.aws_region}::image/ami-*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:${var.aws_region}:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:${var.aws_region}:*:security-group/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

My issue is that subnet ID's pulled into the policy are wrong. My ARN looke like this:

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:subnet/subnet-0bbg694edda209ab9
```

and it should look like this:

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:subnet/0bbg694edda209ab9
```

How do I get just the ID of the subnet (without the subnet-) for use with IAM?

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_IAM.html#subnet-sg-example-iam the first version was correct.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the optimal solution however you could utilise the `replace` interpolation syntax for Terraform. Replacing `"subnet-"` with `""`. The result would look like so

```
arn:aws:ec2:${var.aws_region}:*:subnet/${replace(aws_subnet.prod1.id, "subnet-", "")}
```